# Block IP's In a rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ip

I have a rails app on heroku, and there are about 10 requests per second, which is strange because no one is using the app right now. All of the requests are for URI's that are clearly attempting to exploit security vulnerabilities, for example.

```
http://myapp.com/etc/passwd
```

and things like that.

How can I block this person from accessing my app? Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) will do what you want?

```
# Block requests from 1.2.3.4
Rack::Attack.blacklist('block 1.2.3.4') do |req|
  # Request are blocked if the return value is truthy
  '1.2.3.4' == req.ip
end
```

Comment: Is there a way I could set this up to work dynamically from a database table? How could I make a sort of user-blacklist using this?

Comment: probably, but you would need to engineer that yourself it seems. You may want to look at other Rails options there, if you can find any.

Comment: There's built-in support for Redis, the documentation claims.

Answer (score 3):

My response is a little late but since you had later asked about dynamically adding IPs, might as well share.

From this [Github Issue](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/111). Perhaps you can use the presence/existence of an IP in your cache store to determine if it should be blocked (vs manually adding the IP and re-deploying the app).

```
Rack::Attack.blacklist('block <ip>') do |req|
  # if variable `block <ip>` exists in cache store, then we'll block the request
  Rails.cache.fetch("block #{req.ip}").present?
end
```

From the app or from the console, you can write to your cache store.

```
Rails.cache.write('block 1.2.3.4', true, expires_in: 5.days)
```